Floor Database Not Registering in GetIt
I am trying to make a singleton of the floor database that is globally accessible in my app.
I have tried using this solution:
How to create singleton database object and utilise in different files?
Here is my main app file
  Future<void> main() async {WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  GetIt.I.registerSingletonAsync<AppDatabase>(() async {
    return $FloorAppDatabase.databaseBuilder("MY_DATABASE").build();
  });
  await GetIt.I.allReady();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(const App());
}

and here is the part where I try to call it in my code.
Future<void> _saveDataToDatabase(List<DatingClosedQuestion> closedQuestions,
  List<DatingClosedAnswer> closedAnswers) async {
// Ensure database is initialized globally
final database = GetIt.instance<AppDatabase>();

The error is

Error: Bad state: GetIt: Object/factory with type AppDatabase is not registered inside Getit. (Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance; Did you forget to resigner it?)

I found another solution:
Flutter get_it factory not ready yet [Flutter get_it library with Floor database initialization]
But that did not work either.
Help would be much appreciated!
